# Facebook like button - cannot add "share it on facebook with a comment"

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Problem on facebook like button html :

Facebook is showing [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

That you can add a like button to your site that allows users to also add a comment right
after clicking on the "LIKE" button.

From some reason, when I try that html on my site, it doesn't work.

My site is public and I also got the required META tags inside my  html.

Help, anyone ?

Comment: Are you using iframe or xfbml?

Comment: I used xfbml, but still it doesn't open the rollover for adding a comment. Do I need to set a flag for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting currently only works with the XFBML version:

```
<fb:like></fb:like>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR APP ID', xfbml: true });
</script>
```

Or starting Wednesday (new feature not yet released) the simpler version:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like></fb:like>
```

NOTE: You only need **one** set of the script tags, and you can add as many `<fb:like>` or other XFBML widgets after that.

Comment: Hey. I used that method, but still it doesn't open the rollover for adding a comment. Do I need to set a flag for that?